# Two minor tool-tip problems related to favorite question widgets

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

There are two related minor issues with the favourite button under the scoring widget.

Here's how it looks on the new Skeptics.SE design (but this issue is not related to that design alone)

> [image]

The first issue is that the favorite question count (i.e. the 1) has no tool-tip. If you don't figure out that it belongs with the star widget above it, and you want to know what it means, it won't give you any hint.

The second issue is that the tool-tip for the 'star' remains the same whether it is set or not.

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

To me, this is misleading, as it indicates it already IS a favorite question. The tooltip should change based on the status of the button.

p.s. Just realised the same argument could be applied to the upvote/downvote buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I do agree with some aspects of your concerns, but in using our network of sites the functionality becomes obvious (clicking the favorite button increases the number below it and changes its color, etc.). I am declining this request in favor of other, more broken things that need fixing.